# "Uncaught TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function" while using WebView in Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview, android-webview

I am trying to use WebView in Flutter Application. But when I switched to that page it just shows blank and the below mentioned error is displayed on debug console. Please help me solve this issue, I am stuck with this problem for many days. Thank you!

Code:

```
class ResumaticDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResumaticDashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResumaticDashboard> createState() => _ResumaticDashboardState();
}

class _ResumaticDashboardState extends State<ResumaticDashboard> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;
  bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(
          'https://resumatic.viosa.in/auth?token=${token}')) // this is where i am placing the token.
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _loading = false;
          });
        },
      ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Resumatic Dashboard'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
          if (_loading)
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Error:

```
I/chromium( 5309): [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function", source: https://resumatic.viosa.in/static/js/main.0dc13ca6.js (2)
```

Comment: That error seems to come from the website, not your flutter app. I'm guessing the token you are passing is wrong maybe

Comment: The website itself behaves weird. When trying that url myself in a browser with some made up token it correctly shows a login page the first time, but on refresh it is a blank page. Only after clearing cookies it is able to show a login page again